# how to get total number of pages jspdf-autotable

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying do to a pagination with jspdf-autotable.
But i dont know how to get total number of pages.
When i see the example.js, and use:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('landscape', 'pt', 'a4');
                doc.cellInitialize();
                var tables = $('#resumo_pedido .alert table');
                var res = [];
                var totalPagesExp = "{total_pages_count_string}";

                var splitcomment = doc.splitTextToSize(observacao, 1200); 
                var values = [
                    cnpj,
                    razaoSocial,
                    dataEntrega,
                    localEntrega,
                    meioPagamento,
                    condPagamento,
                    transportadora
                ];

                for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
                    res[i] = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(tables[i]);
                }

                var header = function(data) {
                    doc.setFontSize(10);
                    doc.setTextColor(40);
                    doc.setFontStyle('normal');
                    doc.addImage(
                        'data:image/png;base64,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',
                        'JPEG',
                        data.settings.margin.left, 20
                    );
                    doc.text(values, data.settings.margin.left, 65);
                    doc.text(splitcomment, data.settings.margin.left, 146);

                    var str = "Página " + doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
                    if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
                        str = str + " de " + totalPagesExp;
                    }
                    doc.setFontSize(10);
                    doc.text(str, data.settings.margin.left, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 20);
                };
                var footer = function(data) {
                    var str = "Página " + doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
                    if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
                        str = str + " de " + totalPagesExp;
                    }
                    doc.setFontSize(10);
                    doc.text(str, data.settings.margin.left, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 20);
                };
```

Does not work.
Can someone help me?
Thanks!

EDIT:
Show this on my document.pdf:
[image document footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBQZB.png)

Comment: More details would help - how does it "not work?" Any output? Symptoms? Error messages?

Comment: edit my post with an image

Comment: Can you get the example to work if you copy its code? Are you calling `doc.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp);`?

Comment: edit whit part of code.
how i use doc.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp);?
or...where i use?

Comment: if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
                        doc.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp);
                    }
solved